# Dymanic add Row in LWC and updating the value before push

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, javascript-debugging

i have a JSON Object which has Parent Details, In my page i have an option to add New Row dynamically when i click on `+` button.

```
[
    {
        "canRepeat": true,
        "dynamicName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "dynamicObject": [
            {
                "sectionQuestions": [
                    {                       
                        "question": "Parent First Name",
                        "questionKey": 1,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Last Name",
                        "questionKey": 2,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Email Address",
                        "questionKey": 3,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Phone",
                        "questionKey": 4,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    }
                ],
                "wrapperKey": 1
            }
        ],
        "dynamicSectionName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "id": "a0O4W00001Ux8fKUAR",
        "maxRepeatCount": 2,
        "sectionKey": 1,
        "status": true
    }
]
```

Onclick of + button below JS has been called

```
 var result = Object.values(this.dynamicSectionData).find(obj => obj.id == event.currentTarget.dataset.sectionid)
            .dynamicObject.find(y => {
                return y['wrapperKey'] == 1
            });
        this.copyDynamicSectionData = result;

        // Update Wrapper Key
        var randomTwoDigitNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10);
        console.log('randomTwoDigitNumber --> ' + randomTwoDigitNumber);
        this.copyDynamicSectionData.wrapperKey = randomTwoDigitNumber;

        console.log('result -->' + this.copyDynamicSectionData);
        let responseJson = JSON.stringify(this.copyDynamicSectionData);
        console.log("responseJson -->" + responseJson);

        this.dynamicSectionData[event.currentTarget.dataset.sectionkey].dynamicObject.push(this.copyDynamicSectionData);
```

`result` have a return object and trying to Push into an array. Before Push trying to update `wrapperKey` value as `unique two digit number`

When i print, All the `wrapperKey` value has been updated with same value for that section.

Answer (score 1):

Like Apex and many other languages, JavaScript uses references/pointers to objects, meaning more than one variable/alias can exist for an object. You never actually copied the object you're using, so you end up modifying the object in place. You need to copy it first:

```
this.copyDynamicSectionData = {...result};
```

This makes a shallow copy that should work for your current purposes. You may need to invest in a [recursive copy algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) as you continue your project. Many people just use the JSON.stringify/JSON.parse method:

```
this.copyDynamicSectionData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Which doesn't always work (especially if you have circular references), but should be fine for your use case here.